# Error 500 using C# WebMethod from jQuery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I keep getting error 500 from my ajax function when trying to call WebMethod.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "BookingCalendar.aspx/TestFunction",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error");
    }
});


[WebMethod]
public static string TestFunction()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After more looking I found out that GET and POST are disabled by default in .NET.  I added this to the web.config file:

```
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet"/>
      <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
```

For more information look [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819267).